# Is there potential for Trident to visit a KBO like New Horizons did?

Tags: spacecraft, kuiper-belt, triton

After its flyby of Pluto, New Horizons was also able to visit 486958 Arrokoth achieving secondary scientific goals and providing a picture of a KBO snowman.

Could Trident potentially also be able to visit a KBO after its flyby of Neptune and Triton?

[Trident Paper](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2019/pdf/3200.pdf)
*(This is all done assuming Trident gets selected for the Discovery Program.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the spacecraft is designed for fast flyby of objects to capture and return data from a very long distance, so the potential is there for it to study any object provided it can be put on the right trajectory. The spacecraft's RTG power unit will almost certainly provide enough power for an extended mission - to ensure there's enough for the primary mission engineers will give it more than required - the question would be propulsion for course correction. Again the reserves for the primary mission would allow for an extended mission provided the primary mission goes to plan.